# Javascript Shuffle Array from Txt File

Tags: javascript, arrays, random, text-files, shuffle

I am looking to pull 5 "random" lines from a text file while not repeating any. Each line from the text file has html code which would be inserted into a side menu. I have read up on the Fisher–Yates shuffle but not sure how to incorporate it in this manner with javascript. Presently I have the following throwing an error:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.onload = function() {
    var i = 0;
    // get the file contents
    var fileContent = this.responseText;
    // split into lines
    var fileContentLines = fileContent.split( '\n' );

    var target = document.getElementById( 'random-testimonial' );
    var targetHTML = target.innerHTML;

    while ( i < 5 ) {
        // get a random index (line number)
        var randomLineIndex = Math.floor( Math.random() * fileContentLines.length );
        // extract the value
        var randomLine = fileContentLines[ randomLineIndex ];

        // add the random line in a div if not duplicate            
        if ( ! targetHTML.contains(randomLine) ) {
            targetHTML += randomLine;
            i += 1;
        }
    }

    target.innerHTML = targetHTML;
};
request.open( 'GET', 'content.txt', true );
request.send();
```

and

```
<div id="random-content"><script src="content.js"></script></div>
```

Error:

content.js:19 Uncaught TypeError: targetHTML.contains is not a functionrequest.onload @ content.js:19

Comment: Try substituting `.indexOf()` for `.contains()` at `if` condition

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.onload = function() {
    var i = 0;
    // get the file contents
    var fileContent = this.responseText;
    // split into lines
    var fileContentLines = fileContent.split( '\n' );

    var target = document.getElementById( 'random-testimonial' );

    var HTMLLines = [];

    while ( i < 5 ) {
        // get a random index (line number)
        var randomLineIndex = Math.floor( Math.random() * fileContentLines.length );
        // extract the value
        var randomLine = fileContentLines[ randomLineIndex ];

        // add the random line if not duplicate            
        if ( HTMLLines.indexOf(randomLine) === -1) {
            HTMLLines.push(randomLine);
            i += 1;
        }
    }

    target.innerHTML = HTMLLines.join('\n');
};
request.open( 'GET', 'content.txt', true );
request.send();
```

Comment: Fisher-Yates does not do duplicate/unique checking.

Comment: @naomik please reread his question: I am looking to pull 5 "random" lines from a text file while not repeating any.

My solution solves his error and accomplishes his question with minimal changes to his code. Fisher-Yates was simply something he was considering implementing, but has not yet begun to.

Comment: You can pull 5 random lines without having to do unnecessary duplicate/unique checking. "minimal changes to his code" is not a worthwhile goal if the original code is bad. This approach is lazy, imo. The original code needs so much work here that almost *every* line should be re-worked. Yeah, it takes a ton of effort to explain *why* it needs to be re-worked, but you're not doing any favours by helping beginners write bad code or keep bad code that they've already written.

Comment: Just overwhelmingly disappointed with the lack of effort put forth by people asking other for help.

Comment: @naomik try to understand someone's needs before posting next time. I'm interested in helping someone solve their problem at hand, you're interested in Internet points

Comment: @UltraWeb Hosting glad I could help!

Comment: @TateThurston you couldn't be more wrong. I'm Interested in helping people learn something. Not cheat their way through programming with copy/paste solutions.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so the way Fisher-Yates shuffle works is

- get a random index, `r`, from the input array
- copy element `r` from the input array to the output array
- remove element `r` from the input array
- repeat `n` times, where `n` is the length of the input array

By the end of the loop, the output will be a shuffled copy of the entire input array.

I'm going to glance over one small gotcha: this algorithm shouldn't mutate the input array. Instead it should leave the input array untouched and return a new array that is a shuffled copy of the input array. (You can see how this is done in my implementation below).

So knowing how Fisher-Yates works, in your case, we don't have to shuffle the *entire* array since you know before-hand that you only want `N` elements.

Let's first look at your input.

```
var fileContent = this.responseText;
var fileContentLines = fileContent.split( '\n' );
```

OK, perfect. You've defined the input array, `fileContentLines`. Now let's make a function to sample some random elements from it

```
// fisher-yates sample
// • sample n elements from xs
// • does not mutate xs
// • guarantees each sampled element is unique
function sample (n,xs) {
  function loop(i, output, input, len) {
    if (i === n) return output;                   // loop exit condition
    let r = Math.floor(Math.random() * len);      // rand number between 0 and len
    return loop(                                  // continue loop
      i + 1,                                      // increment loop counter
      output.concat(input[r]),                    // copy element r from input
      input.slice(0,r).concat(input.slice(r+1)),  // remove element from input
      len - 1                                     // decrement length
    );
  }
  return loop(0, [], xs, xs.length);              // begin loop
}
```

Alright ! Let's first check it with a simple input

```
// sample 3 random inputs from numbers 1 through 10
console.log(sample(3, [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])); //=> [9,7,5]
```

Perfect. Now just call it on your array of lines

```
var result = sample(5, fileContentLines);
console.log(result); // ...
```

---

The above code works, but let's not stop here. Our code is taking on too much responsibility and we can separate some of the behaviours into reusable functions.

```
// get rand number between 0 and n
function rand(x) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * x);
}

// splice of xs at index i
// • return a new output array
// • does not mutate xs
function del(i,xs) {
  return xs.slice(0,i).concat(xs.slice(i+1));
}

// fisher-yates sample
// • sample n elements from xs
// • does not mutate xs
// • guarantees each sampled element is unique
function sample (n,xs) {
  function loop(i, output, input, len) {
    if (i === n) return output;       // loop exit condition
    let r = rand(len);                // rand number between 0 and len
    return loop(                      // continue loop
      i + 1,                          // increment loop counter
      output.concat(input[r]),        // copy element r from input
      del(r,input),                   // remove element from input
      len - 1                         // decrement length
    );
  }
  return loop(0, [], xs, xs.length);  // begin loop
}

// fisher-yates shuffle
// • does not mutate xs
function shuffle(xs) {
  return sample(xs.length, xs);
}
```

Let's take a quick look at the individual behaviour of each function

```
// generate random number between 0 and 10 (exclusive)
console.log(rand(10)); //=> 5

// delete 2nd letter from letters a through d
console.log(del(1, ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])); // => ['a', 'c', 'd]

// sample 3 random inputs from numbers 1 through 10
console.log(sample(3, [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])); //=> [9,7,5]

// shuffle entire input array
console.log(shuffle([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])); //=> [8,9,1,3,7,6,10,5,4,2]
```

And there you have it: **4 functions for the price of 1**. In my opinion, this is a much better way to solve the problem because each function is useful on its own and therefore can be used in multiple places. Having lots of little reusable functions will drastically reduce the amount of work you'll have to do in the future.

---

With all of this complexity nicely compartmentalized, let's see what your final code might look like.

```
function createParagraph(text) {
  var p = document.createElement('p');
  p.innerHTML = text;
  return p;
}

var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.onload = function() {

  var fileContent = this.responseText;
  var fileContentLines = fileContent.split('\n');
  var target = document.getElementById('random-testimonial');

  sample(5, fileContentLines).map(function(testimonial) {
    var p = createParagraph(testimonial);
    target.appendChild(p);
  });
};
request.open('GET', 'content.txt', true);
request.send();
```

**PS** I highly recommend you write reusable functions for your ajax requests, or better, use a library. Writing them by hand is extremely cumbersome and error prone. Most people use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) but lately I've been reaching for [axios](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios)

Comment: @SirajHussain wups, I had a little typo in there ^_^. I had `.splice` where I intended `.slice`. Thanks for your eagle eyes.

Comment: I really do appreciate the time you spent on your reply naomik. I am not a code writer and your response is a bit inundating to me as I just require a simple solution to a script which will not be used all too often that can be integrated easily. Throwing in your code I receive :
content.js:14 Uncaught ReferenceError: sample is not definedrequest.onload @ content.js:14

Comment: Yeah, so you did it wrong. OK, this was a waste of effort. Lesson learned.